# WCF- how to add multiple services to Service.svc?

Tags: wcf

I have 4 services running via a service host project, which communicate fine with my asp.net application when the ASP.NET development server hosts them through VS for debugging.

I am trying to deploy these to IIS on a windows server 2008 machine, using WAS.

I have the project set up as an application in IIS, and have copied the entire  config section from app.config in servicehost project to web.config of the IIS site.

After a few compliation issues, I now get a directory listing when i navigate to http://localhost:8000/Services

I have also created a Service.svc file, which contains 
    <%@ServiceHost Service=MyApp.AddressService %>

When I navigate to localhost:8000/Services/AddressService, I get a message that i've created a service, and appending ?wsdl gives me the xml to create a client.

Problem is, I get an error when I try to add any more services to the .svc file.

Should I be using service.svc to configure multiple services, or is there a different way using WAS?
How can I expose my other three services through the same application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You cannot add multiple service to a SVC file. One SVC file = one service class. No way to change that.

However: you can definitely implement multiple service interfaces on your service class:

```
public class YourService : IService1, IService2, IService3
{
  ... 
}
```

and then you have one SVC file = one service (implementation) class = 3 service contracts.

In .NET 4 / WCF 4, you'll be able to define URL's for service in your web.config, and you don't need the SVC files anymore.

See [this blog post here](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2009/05/whats-new-in-wcf4-svc-less-activation---or-look-ma-my-rest-urls-look-good.html) or [this one here](http://thoughtorientedarchitecture.blogspot.com/2010/04/wcf-40-file-less-activation-and-custom.html) for more info, if .NET 4 is an option for you.